# Duply / Duplicity backup fails cause of no such file or directory

Tags: svn, backup, remote-backup, duplicity, duplicity-backup

I am using duply / Duplicity to backup my /var/www directory, but the task is not working. It always fails with following error message:

```
    Copying duplicity-new-signatures.20150827T090338Z.to.20150828T000005Z.sigtar.gz to local cache.
    [...]
    Copying duplicity-new-signatures.20150828T000005Z.to.20150828T044355Z.sigtar.gz to local cache.
    Copying duplicity-new-signatures.20150828T044355Z.to.20150828T062114Z.sigtar.gz to local cache.
    Warning, found incomplete backup sets, probably left from aborted session
    Last full backup date: Sat May 16 02:00:35 2015
    Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/example.de/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/img/.svn/lock' getting delta for example.de/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/img/.svn/lock
    Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/example.com/sites/all/themes/default/radar/js/model/.svn/lock' getting delta for example.com/sites/all/themes/default/radar/js/model/.svn/lock
    --------------[ Backup Statistics ]--------------
    StartTime 1440753923.05 (Fri Aug 28 11:25:23 2015)
    EndTime 1440758448.61 (Fri Aug 28 12:40:48 2015)
    ElapsedTime 4525.56 (1 hour 15 minutes 25.56 seconds)
    SourceFiles 3470665
    SourceFileSize 35369709861 (32.9 GB)
    NewFiles 112298
    NewFileSize 9001483 (8.58 MB)
    DeletedFiles 2553
    ChangedFiles 36251
    ChangedFileSize 107956213 (103 MB)
    ChangedDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
    DeltaEntries 151102
    RawDeltaSize 76391479 (72.9 MB)
    TotalDestinationSizeChange 17917453 (17.1 MB)
    Errors 2
    -------------------------------------------------

    --- Finished state OK at 12:41:10.546 - Runtime 01:25:34.364 ---

    --- Start running command POST at 12:41:10.622 ---
    Skipping n/a script '/root/.duply/www-backup/post'.
    --- Finished state OK at 12:41:10.691 - Runtime 00:00:00.069 ---
```

On the one hand it says "Finished state OK" and on the other it says "Errors 2". It's a bit confusing.

Ok, this may signify, that the backup was successful, but regarding the "Errors 2" message, I better want to fix it, that I am receiving "Errors 0" in future.

There are some cronjobs, which runs "svn update" every 7 minutes on the system.

Does anyone has an idea? I am looking forward to your answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no reason to be worried.

the output merely states that mentioned files could not be accessed, which is possible for lock files.

the backup finished OK otherwise, these files will not be included. consider adding a globbing expression for svn lock files e.g.

```
- **/.svn/lock
```

to your exclude file.

..ede/duply.net